# Converting asio read_some to async version

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I have the following code that reads from a TCP socket using boost asio read_some function. Currently the code is synchronous and I need to convert it to the async version. The issue is initially that some bytes are read to identify the packettype and to get the length of the packet. Then we have a loop that reads the data. Would I need to use two callbacks to do this asynchronously or can it be done with one ( which would be preferable).

```
   void Transport::OnReadFromTcp()
    {
        int read = 0;
        // read 7 bytes from TCP into mTcpBuffer
        m_sslsock->read_some(asio::buffer(mTcpBuffer, 7));

        bool tag = true;
        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tag = tag && (mTcpBuffer[i] == g_TcpPacketTag[i]);

        }

        // get the length from the last two bytes
        unsigned short dataLen = (mTcpBuffer[5] ) | (mTcpBuffer[6] << 8);
        mBuff = new char[dataLen];

        int readTotal = 0;
        while (readTotal < dataLen)
        {
            // read lengths worth of data from tcp pipe into buffer
            int readlen = dataLen;

           size_t read = m_sslsock->read_some(asio::buffer(&mBuff[readTotal], readlen));
           readlen = dataLen - read;
            readTotal += read;

        }
        // Process data .....
    }
```

Comment: You need to perform a loop using async_read and maintain a state of where you are in regards to the data that you read.

async_read callback initiates another async_read and so on.
Also note that you might not be able to read all of your packet's data at once even after you retrieved the packet length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to realize that you can remove the `read_some` loop entireyl using the free function `read`:

```
void Transport::OnReadFromTcp() {
    int read = 0;

    // read 7 bytes from TCP into mTcpBuffer
    size_t bytes = asio::read(*m_sslsock, asio::buffer(mTcpBuffer, 7), asio::transfer_all());
    assert(bytes == 7);

    bool tag = g_TcpPacketTag.end() == std::mismatch(
                    g_TcpPacketTag.begin(), g_TcpPacketTag.end(),
                    mTcpBuffer.begin(), mTcpBuffer.end())
                .first;

    // get the length from the last two bytes
    uint16_t const dataLen = mTcpBuffer[5] | (mTcpBuffer[6] << 8);
    mBuff.resize(dataLen);

    size_t readTotal = asio::read(*m_sslsock, asio::buffer(mBuff), asio::transfer_exactly(dataLen));

    assert(mBuff.size() == readTotal);
    assert(dataLen == readTotal);
}
```

That's even regardless of whether execution is asynchronous.

Making it asynchronous is slightly involved, because it requires assumptions about lifetime of the buffers/`Transport` instance as well as potential multi-threading. I'll provide a sample of that after my morning coffee :)

---

Demo without threading/lifetime complications:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d478e6d4a46b228f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;


namespace {
    static std::array<char, 5> g_TcpPacketTag {{'A','B','C','D','E'}};
}

struct Transport {
    using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;
    using SslSocket = std::shared_ptr<asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> >;

    Transport(SslSocket s) : m_sslsock(s) { }

    void OnReadFromTcp();
    void OnHeaderReceived(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t transferred);
    void OnContentReceived(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t transferred);
  private:
    uint16_t datalen() const {
        return mTcpBuffer[5] | (mTcpBuffer[6] << 8);
    }

    SslSocket m_sslsock;

    std::array<char, 7> mTcpBuffer;
    std::vector<char> mBuff;
};

void Transport::OnReadFromTcp() {
    // read 7 bytes from TCP into mTcpBuffer
    asio::async_read(*m_sslsock, asio::buffer(mTcpBuffer, 7), asio::transfer_all(),
                boost::bind(&Transport::OnHeaderReceived, this, asio::placeholders::error, asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
            );
}

#include <boost/range/algorithm/mismatch.hpp> // I love sugar

void Transport::OnHeaderReceived(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes) {
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    }

    assert(bytes == 7);

    bool tag = (g_TcpPacketTag.end() == boost::mismatch(g_TcpPacketTag, mTcpBuffer).first);

    if (tag) {
        // get the length from the last two bytes
        mBuff.resize(datalen());

        asio::async_read(*m_sslsock, asio::buffer(mBuff), asio::transfer_exactly(datalen()),
                boost::bind(&Transport::OnContentReceived, this, asio::placeholders::error, asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
            );

    } else {
        std::cout << "TAG MISMATCH\n"; // TODO handle error
    }
}

void Transport::OnContentReceived(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t readTotal) {
    assert(mBuff.size() == readTotal);
    assert(datalen() == readTotal);

    std::cout << "Successfully completed receive of " << datalen() << " bytes\n";
}

int main() {
    asio::io_service svc;

    using Socket = Transport::SslSocket::element_type;

    // connect to localhost:6767 with SSL
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
    auto s = std::make_shared<Socket>(svc, ctx);
    s->lowest_layer().connect({ {}, 6767 });
    s->handshake(Socket::handshake_type::client);

    // do transport
    Transport tx(s);
    tx.OnReadFromTcp();

    svc.run();

    // all done
    std::cout << "All done\n";
}
```

When using against a sample server that accepts SSL connections on port 6767:

```
(printf "ABCDE\x01\x01F"; cat main.cpp) |
     openssl s_server -accept 6767 -cert so.crt -pass pass:test
```

Prints:

```
Successfully completed receive of 257 bytes
All done
```

Comment: Added a demo showing the async version as well [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d478e6d4a46b228f). Recorded live-coding this answer: [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/asynchronous-ssl-receive-headerpayload/)

Comment: Alternatives: [c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f5f9f8982491509), [c++11 lambdas](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b34991631783b69), [coroutines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc70ec6f2565781a) (broken on Coliru, but runs fine here). With the `shared_from_this` idiom to keep `Transfer` alive: [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/921e384a63dc7ca1)